# Difference between RTCPeerConnection.createDataChannel() and RTCPeerConnection.onDataChannel()

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I have been playing around with webRTC lately and am creating an abstraction layer to easily get multiple client communication via a mesh network architecture.

The question I have is in regards to creating the data channel. At the moment i do the following:

```
var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(null, {optional: []});

var conn = pc.createDataChannel("testchannel", {});
var conn2 = null;
conn.onmessage = function(evt){
    console.log("onmessage1");
};

pc.ondatachannel = function (event) {
    conn2 = event.channel;
    event.channel.onmessage = function(evt){
        console.log("onmessage2");
    };
};
```

Which results in what seems like 2 full-duplex channels being opened up between the 2 clients. i.e. calling `conn.send("message")` will result in `onmessage1` but calling `conn2.send("message")` will result in `onmessage2`. Is this the normal behaviour or is there something wrong with my setup?

For a bit of extra information I am testing using Chrome42 with [adapter.js](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/trunk/samples/js/base/adapter.js?r=4259)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A data channel is indeed bi-directional; you only need to create one data channel for two peers to communicate over. Just as the initial RTC connection needs* to be created by *one* peer sending an offer and the other responding, a data channel needs to be opened by *one* peer and the other can latch onto it in `ondatachannel`. Then both will use `send` and `on message` of that data channel to communicate.

<sub>* Note that you *can* create "negotiated" data channels. Each data channel has an id; you can simply manually assign an id to your data channel. If both peers open a data channel with the same id, they do not need to "negotiate" it and can simply assume the other end is listening to the same channel. In practice I have found this to be flaky though.</sub>

Comment: So I guess the problem is that the code I have shown above is executed by both clients?

Comment: Right. You should have some mechanism to determine a *callee* and a *caller* role; the caller will initiate all the connections and channels and the callee will merely respond to them. Your signalling server could assign those roles, or you can use some three-way-handshake scheme to negotiate those roles on the fly, or perhaps your peers already have some unique id and you can simply use a rule where the lower id will always be the caller or such, or you clearly do have two different versions of the code running to begin with.

Comment: The datachannel actually *can* be created by both. There is a negotiated field in `createDataChannel` that can be used. See the [Official Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#widl-RTCDataChannelInit-negotiated) for more information. Then you just have to make sure that the `id` is the same. In general I would not recommend doing so.

Comment: just a warning, there was a bug that did not let firefox create datachannel when connecting to chrome, (not sure if fixed yet), in this case, make a mechanism that would check which peerconnection is chrome browser and create data channel from that browser.

Comment: @Robert True, added a note about that.

Comment: Thanks, all fixed. I was setting a flag to decide who would create an offer and who would create the answer. I have simply used that flag to determine who should `createDataChannel` and who should listen for a created datachannel (`ondatachannel`)

Answer (score 1):

- create datachannel is active while on datachannel is passive.
- the caller would call createdatachannel which would return a rtcdatachannel object that can be later used to send object and other things using it s own events (onmessage/onopen/onclose).
- the callee would make sure to attach a function to the corresponding peerconnection's ondatachannel event which would extract the rtcdatachannel object from the event ( mychannel = event.channel ).